# Split and remove new line

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I try to split text by comma and add to list each one. Text sample:

> user 1 , role 1
>
> user 2 , role 2
> user 3 , role 3
>
> ```
>  user 4 , role 4
>
>  user 5 , role 5
> ```

Function:

```
private Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
public String splitString(String sentence) {
    List<String> list;
    String[] dividedByNewLine = sentence.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dividedByNewLine.length; i++) {
            String[] divideByComma = dividedByNewLine[i].split(",");
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < divideByComma.length; j++) {
                list.add(divideByComma[j].trim());
            }
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                map.put(i, list);
            }
            System.out.println(map.get(i));
       
    }

    return null;
}
```

But function build list like that:

> [user 1 , role 1]
>
> []
>
> [user 2 , role 2]
>
> [user 3 , role 3]
>
> []
>
> [user 4 , role 4]
>
> []
>
> [user 5 , role 5]

How can I delete "[]" in list?

Comment: this is because `toString` method has list representation that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dividedByNewLine.length; i++) {
        if(!dividedByNewLine[i].trim().equals("")) {
            String[] divideByComma = dividedByNewLine[i].split(",");

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < divideByComma.length; j++) {
            list.add(divideByComma[j].trim());
        }
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            map.put(i, list);
        }
        System.out.println(map.get(i));
        }
}
```

Basically, you have to skip the empty lines.

Comment: "if(!dividedByNewLine[i].trim().equals("")) " code block worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because your input have empty line. If you don't want to show empty line, your should code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dividedByNewLine.length; i++) {
    if (!dividedByNewLine[i].trim().isEmpty()){
      String[] divideByComma = dividedByNewLine[i].split(",");
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < divideByComma.length; j++) {
                list.add(divideByComma[j].trim());
            }
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                map.put(i, list);
            }
            System.out.println(map.get(i));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search in `dividedByNewLine` all lines that are empty and delete them! Then you'll get

```
user 1 , role 1
user 2 , role 2
user 3 , role 3
user 4 , role 4
user 5 , role 5
```

Or `dividedByNewLine[i].split(",")` for `dividedByNewLine` that are not empty:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dividedByNewLine.length; i++) 
{
    if(!dividedByNewLine[i].isEmpty())
    {
        String[] divideByComma = dividedByNewLine[i].split(",");

        ...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate `[]` before adding to list:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < dividedByNewLine.length; i++) {
        String[] divideByComma = dividedByNewLine[i].split(",");

        //Add this control statement
        if(divideByComma.isEmpty())
        continue;       //If the string is empty then continue the loop

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < divideByComma.length; j++) {
            list.add(divideByComma[j].trim());
        }
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            map.put(i, list);
        }
        System.out.println(map.get(i));

}
```